# How to pass any directory format (windows, linux, mac) to a function and use it os independently (python3)

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, pathlib

You can make os independent a file-name with:

os.path.join(os.path.curdir, 'filename')

But I need something else. I want my function to take whatever path format (windows, linux, mac), to convert it to os independent format, in order to assign it at a variable and work with it at any os. Also, note that the filename is not necessarily at the curent directory.

example:

```py
def magically_read_any_path_format_and_make_it_os_independent(input_file)
    ...
    return os_independent_format

# my variable
file = magically_...(input_file)
```

P.S. I know I can check whether it is the one or the other os and make the corresponding conversions, but is there something more automated and pythonic? Something in os or pathlib or elsewhere?

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase

Comment: Pretty sure [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) already does this for you. Creating a `Path` object will create the necessary platform-specific subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using python `> 3.4` you can use `pathlib` and it does exactly that. You create a `Path` object from your path and it handles everything for you.

On older versions of Python, as long as you use `os.path` for any path manipulations you need, and use the Unix format for any hard-coded constants together with `os.path.normpath`, it should work on any os.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you mean by os independent the docs state that "os.path module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths" meaning it gives you what you need locally.

You may be able to 
`os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, '')` which is rather hacky

or

`os.path.normpath(os.path.curdir)` which may do more then you want, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html?highlight=path#os.path.normpath)